# Multisig seed recovery wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mnemonic-seed, multisig

Okay, so I recovered a multi-sig wallet from seed using the `monero-wallet-cli`. The multi-sig was already created (scheme 2/3), I used my original wallet seed and then completed the recovery with the information (`import_multisig_info`, etc.) from the other two wallets.

When I finally synced the multi-sig wallet without the last transaction history my balance showed me as if the wallet was created as a view-only wallet. I will try to explain, it showed the total of XMR summed, it didn't show me the latest transactions. Then I did the `import_multisig_info` again from one of the other wallets and then finally the balance was correct.

I know for each transaction you need to `import_multisig_info` to update the multi-sig wallet, but seeing the balance with only the first signatures to create the wallet makes it a kind of "view-only wallet"?

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase please? I can't quite see what your question is. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'll try. Why was my multi-sig wallet showing a bigger amount of XMR in balance when I recovered from seed?